# Find the medium of an array by modifying quick sort that also has an average O(n) time complexity

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion, time-complexity

Please help me. I need to modify quicksort with an average of O(n) time complexity that just sorts half of the array as I'm just trying to find the medium of the array.

Heres my quicksort algorithm before any changes:

```
   static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j){
      int temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = temp;
   }
  
   static int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high){
      int pivot = arr[high]; 
      int i = (low - 1); 
   
      for(int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++){
         if (arr[j] < pivot) {
            i++; 
            swap(arr, i, j);
         }
      }
      swap(arr, i + 1, high);
      return (i + 1);
   }
  
   static void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high){
      if (low < high) {
         int pi = partition(arr, low, high);
         quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
         quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
      }
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by average of O(n) time complexity? Quicksort can only be up to O(n log(n)), and at worst O(n²).

Comment: That's what I thought but apparently because I'm trying to find just the median, I only need to check one side of the pivot not the whole array.

Comment: When you partition a list, you know what position the pivot will assume in the final sorted list --- the length of the list containing all elements lower. Example: if you have a list (array) [4, 5, 3, 8, 6, 2] and you choose 4 as your pivot, you'll get [3, 2] and [5, 8, 6] as your two partitions, so you know 4 will be the 3rd element of the list (position 2 counting from 0).

Comment: If you want an element that comes before in the sorted list, you search the first partition, if you want an element that comes after, you search the second one.

The medium, for lists of odd length l, is just the element in position l/2 (counting from 0) in the sorted list.